# PHP: extract data from XML string and add to array

Tags: php, xml, arrays, loops, foreach

I have an XML string resulting from an SQL query that looks like the following (shortened). 
My website is set up to fetch this from SQL and $objRev->reviews->countries would give me the content of the countries part for each of the reviews in the XML.

Countries only contains text (country names) separated by comma and space.

**In the below example my input variables would be:**

```
var1 = "Austria, Belgium, Bulgaria, Croatia, Cyprus";
var2 = "Brazil, Sweden, United Kingdom";
```

**Expected output:** "Austria, Belgium, Brazil, Bulgaria, Croatia, Cyprus, Sweden, United Kingdom"

Can someone tell me how I can use PHP to combine the content of these variables in an array and sort them alphabetically ?
My challenge here is that there are not always two variables, it can also be one or more as this depends on whether the review date matches a given input, here: 2014-04-21 - the indicator for this is `dateMatch = 'Yes'`.

```
<root>
  <reviews>
    <review>2014-04-21</review>
    <revLong>21 Apr 2014</revLong>
    <revShort>2014-04-21</revShort>
    <dayDiff>0</dayDiff>
    <revStatus>past</revStatus>
    <countries>Austria, Belgium, Bulgaria, Croatia, Cyprus</countries>
    <dateMatch>Yes</dateMatch>
    <countryMatch>Yes</countryMatch>
  </reviews>
  <reviews>
    <review>2014-04-21</review>
    <revLong>21 Apr 2014</revLong>
    <revShort>2014-04-21</revShort>
    <dayDiff>0</dayDiff>
    <revStatus>past</revStatus>
    <countries>Brazil, Sweden, United Kingdom</countries>
    <dateMatch>Yes</dateMatch>
    <countryMatch>No</countryMatch>
  </reviews>
</root>
```

Many thanks for any help with this, Tim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something simple like this.. Use [`simplexml_load_string()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php)

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
foreach ($xml->reviews as $child)
{
        $cnt[]=explode(',',$child->countries);
}
$arr = array_map('trim',call_user_func_array('array_merge',$cnt));
sort($arr);
echo implode(', ',$arr);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Austria, Belgium, Brazil, Bulgaria, Croatia, Cyprus, Sweden, United Kingdom
```

<kbd>[Demonstration](https://eval.in/144891)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works great - I just had to replace the foreach in your answer as follows to limit this to the dates I am interested in: if($child->dateMatch == "Yes") { $cnt[] = explode(",",$child->countries); } - can you explain what "call_user_func_array" does here ?

Comment: @user2571510, The results are generated under nested arrays, so the `call_user_func_array` uses an `array_merge` to merge those arrays.

Comment: Thanks again ! One more question on this: If I need to add something to each of the countries (e.g. an img tag before each country name), how would I do this using your solution ?

Comment: You can use an `array_walk` for that.. Add this `array_walk($arr,function (&$v){ $v = '<img src="someimage.jpg"/>'.$v;});` after the `sort($arr);`

Comment: Thanks. I would need to do this before the sort, maybe even in the foreach as each image will have the same name as its country - sorry, I didn't mention that before.

Comment: <img src="Australia.jpg" /> Australia, <img src="Belgium.jpg" /> Belgium, <img src="Brazil.jpg" /> Brazil ...

Comment: You need to use this after the `sort()` call ... `array_walk($arr,function (&$v){ $v = "<img src='".$v.".jpg'/>".$v;});`

Answer (score 0):

Try with array_merge, sort and array_unique functions:

```
$all = array_unique(sort(array_merge($var1, $var2)));
```

Comment: The `sort()` returns a boolean value and you cannot pass that to `array_unique`. It will not work.